# What is the state of $s0 after the program is finished running?

Tags: assembly, mips

I know that "addi $s0, $zero, 1" stores 1 into $s0, but I am unsure about the rest of the code. This was a question I missed on one of my tests for my assembly language class and I'm trying to learn the answer for my final in a few days. Any help is very appreciated. I also wanted to add that all of our coding was done in MIPS.

```
addi $s0, $zero, 1
sll $s0, $s0, 8
addi $s0, $s0, 34
```

Comment: why not just try it in spim or other?

Comment: in addition or independently please edit  your question to describe instruction by instruction what you think it is doing so we can understand if you have it right or wrong, and where.

Comment: I tried it in MIPS and it didn't help. I also said as much as I knew about it, This is my first assembly code class, and I am having trouble understanding. I know sll means shift left logical, but I don't understand what happened to $s0 in that line. And I don't understand what is happening in the 3rd line either

Comment: so you have some mips documentation and have looked up the instruction yes?  What did that documentation say?

Comment: When I ran it, it said that it ran successfully. I did add some other code to print the code above and I got the number 290....

Comment: The first instruction add 1 and 0 and put it in s0.So s0=1 . The SLL does a logical shift left of s0 by 8 bits with result in s0. which is the same as multiplying s0 by 2^8(256).So s0=1*256=0. Then 34 is added to s0 and result in s0 which would be 290.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: I meant 1*256=256 (0 was a typo)

Comment: you can try also MARS (MIPS simulator written in Java, so it runs almost under any OS), where under help there is list of all instructions with description, but if you are also struggling "what logical shift left means", then try to search for some computer architecture text, explaining what are bits, bytes, and how information is encoded in computers, etc. Once you realize that every information in computer is encoded as 0/1 values (bits), you can try to practice a bit more basic math in binary, so you can yourself calculate 0101 + 0011 etc, then shifting those bits should be easy to grasp.

Comment: BTW, don't just "run" your assembly code after writing it. Always use first debugger to step over single instructions, and confront the results after every step both against your assumptions about single instruction being executed, and against your total master plan/algorithm, if the immediate results make sense and are part of it. Just moving bits around randomly and writing random instructions you are not sure about, expecting you will hit the result by accident, is very wrong in assembly, try always focus to break down into it so much, that you really understand what each instruction does.

Comment: It computes `(1<<8) + 34`.

Answer (score 0):

**First statement:** register s0 -> **1**

**Second statement:**  Shift logical left of 8 bits: `1<<8` = **256**

**Third statement:**  register s0: **256+34**